# How to Filter/Search Lists without a link

Tags: javascript

How would this script possibly work even if I delete all `<a href="#">` and `</a>` tags from the list?
See the working example source code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list).
Thank you!

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">    
<ul id="myUL">
    <li>Adele</li>
    <li>Agnes</li>
    <li>Billy</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
</ul>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why you have removed the <a>'s - in the example at the link you provide - they are there - eg: <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li> and if your point was that in order for the function to work - then there has to be an a element - then yes that is true - but the function could equally be modified to simply check for and filter the text on the li innerHTML - so not sure what your point is in asking this question.

Comment: Can the script work for any list even without the <a href="#"></a> Tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        if (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed the need for an 'a' tag - it is just using the .innerHTML directly inside the 'li' tag.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to make it work for <ul> with a class and not an id?  
<ul class="myUL">
    <li>Adele</li>
    <li>Agnes</li>
    <li>Billy</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
</ul>

Comment: yes remplace getElementById or getElementsByTagName by querySelectorAll(".myClass"); querySelectorAll("ul.myClass"); querySelectorAll("li.otherClass"); so final document.querySelectorAll(".className")

Comment: I can't make it work.. See my latest post.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

isn't so difficult :(. But isn't a good practice ...

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        if (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">    
<ul id="myUL">
    <li>Adele</li>
    <li>Agnes</li>
    <li>Billy</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to make it work for <ul> with a class and not an id? <ul class="myUL">..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach to filter a list. It works with or without an `<a>` in the list's elements (`li`) and would work with `div` or whatever element in the to be filtered list, too. It depends on a data-attribute being set on the input, which determines which list should be filtered.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('myInput');

input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let el = e.currentTarget,
    value = el.value.toUpperCase(),
    list = document.getElementById(el.getAttribute("data-filters")),
    lis = Array.from(list.children);
  lis.forEach(li => {
    li.classList.toggle('hidden', !li.innerText.toUpperCase().includes(value));
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" data-filters="myUL" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li>Agnes</li>
  <li>Billy</li>
  <div>Bob</div>
</ul>
```

Note that IE doesn't have support for the second argument to `classList.toggle`, but you can easily use the Polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

How would this possibly work with different lists and classes?

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">    
    <ul class="myUL">
        <li>Adele</li>
        <li>Agnes</li>
        <li>Billy</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="myUL2">
        <li>Adele</li>
        <li>Agnes</li>
        <li>Billy</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="myUL3">
        <li>Adele</li>
        <li>Agnes</li>
        <li>Billy</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
    </ul>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById('myInput');
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById('archive');
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            if (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```